# How to set the istio sidecar lifecycle

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-sidecar

How can I configure something so that the injected istio sidecar uses the recent kubernetes container lifecycle of sidecar? The sidecar lifecycle is discussed [here](https://medium.com/@chan_seeker/sidecar-containers-improvement-in-kubernetes-1-18-b5eb66ee2b83) and [here](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/k8s-sidecars/). More specifically is there an annotation similar to `sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"`, or some other attributes in a CRD, that can do this? I am using istio 1.6. Thank you.

Comment: Did you know, that you are using very old and deprecated version of Istio? Actual [release](https://istio.io/latest/docs/releases/supported-releases/) is 1.11

Comment: yep. using openshift 4.7. not my choice. :(

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned Kubernetes sidecar proposal was withdrawn. So there is no support for that, neither in Istio 1.6 nor in more recent versions.

See https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/753